# How to exit powershell invoked from psexec

Tags: batch-file, powershell, psexec

I am trying to call a powershell script using psexec which connects to remote system

So from "Computer A" I call the batch file Aot.bat which is on "Computer B"

Aot.bat has a line which calls the powershell

powershell.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\aot.ps1 -ComputerName AotServ01 >>\Aot01\AOtShared\Yuma.txt;exit

I can see that the connection is made and powershell runs, but then it does not exit

So please advise what can be done or added

Aot.ps1 reads the Memory and CPU at the present Moment

---

```
[cmdletbinding()]            
[cmdletbinding()]
param(        
 [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]            
 [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername) 

begin {
Get-Module –ListAvailable | import-module
Add-PSSnapin Citrix*
Set-executionpolicy -scope currentuser -executionpolicy unrestricted

$date = Get-Date -Format yyyMMdd
$Zip = "\\na02\KCRC\IRD_KFLOWRPT\Citrix_" + $date + "\Citrix_" + $date + ".txt"
$time = Get-Date -format F

}            

process 
{            

foreach($Computer in $Computername) 
 {

$free = ( Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer ).FreePhysicalMemory
$phys = ( Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer ).TotalVisibleMemorySize
$Percentage = (($phys-$free)/$Phys) * 100

$proc =get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 2

$cpu=($proc.readings -split ":")[-1]

write-host "`r`n*********************************************************************************"
write-host "`r`nComputer: " $computer
write-host "`r`n_________________________________________________________________________________"
write-host "`r`nPercentage Memory user Used: " $Percentage
write-host "`r`n"
write-host "`r`nPercentage CPU Used: " $cpu
write-host "`r`n_________________________________________________________________________________"
write-host "`r`n"
write-host $time
 }            
}            

end 
{
write-host "`r`n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
write-host "`r`n            END OF FILE                      "
write-host "`r`n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
}
===============================================================================
```

Comment: Why not use PowerShell Remoting instead? You can return remote PowerShell objects from a remote session to your local session, and work with them locally. It's much easier than trying to use psexec with PowerShell.

Comment: The PowerShell script should exit on its own.  You don't need to append `;exit` to the psexec command.  Try executing it like so `powershell.exe -command "& {& "$env:SystemRoot\system32\aot.ps1" -ComputerName AotServ01 >> \Aot01\AOtShared\Yuma.txt}"`

Comment: I tried to use the command as suggested by Keith, and it does not dump the output onto the text file. If I try running the batch using command prompt I can see it in the command window. How do I pipe it into text file.
Any ideas??
I cannot use Powershell Remoting as I have restrictions in place

Comment: The syntax for piping the output of a command to a text document is `COMMAND >> TEXTFILE.TXT`. Try `powershell.exe -command "& {& "$env:SystemRoot\system32\aot.ps1" -ComputerName AotServ01 >> \Aot01\AOtShared\Yuma.txt}" >> textfile.exe`.

Comment: I figured this out
I had force the psexec to start the batch and move on, and once the batch file ends the handle on the output file gets released
psexec -u aotdomain\aot -p "**&*&*&" \\AOT01 -d cmd /c "E:\Aotdump\AOT.bat"